# Android On / Off Push Notification when On / off Toggle button

Tags: android

How to enable/disable Push Notification using a `ToggleButton`

**Example:**

`ToggleButton` Disable (OFF) >>> Push Notification Should Stop

`ToggleButton` Enable (ON) >>> Push Notification Shouid strat

```
// turn on/off push notification
    if (isChecked){
        prefNotification.edit().putBoolean(Constant.PREF_KEY, true).commit();
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getApplicationContext(),YOUR_CLASS.class);
        Toast.makeText(CatalogActivity.this, "turn on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else{
        prefNotification.edit().putBoolean(Constant.PREF_KEY_TOGGLE_NOTIFICATION, false).commit();
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getApplicationContext(), null);
        Toast.makeText(CatalogActivity.this, "turn off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use this code inside your toggle button listener
if(isChecked)
{
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

     Editor editor = settings.edit();
     editor.putString("push", "true");
     editor.commit();
}
else
{
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

     Editor editor = settings.edit();
     editor.putString("push", "false");
     editor.commit();
}

and receiver class
show push notification according to shared Preference Flag
```